# How do I make the mouse cursor larger in Artful Aardvark?

Tags: cursor

How do I make the mouse cursor larger in Artful Aardvark?

Comment: This isn't a forum but a Q&A website. Please [edit] and divide it into a Q and an A.

Answer (score 0):

From the questioner, Preacherdad:

> 1. Go to the **power button** (upper right of screen) and click on the **Tool Set** icon.
> 2. When that comes up, choose the **Universal Access** option from the menu on the left of the window.
> 3. On the right of that window, there is an option to change the cursor size.